# Android - images dynamically added wth whitespace?

Tags: android, imageview, whitespace

I am adding dynamically my images into activity like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, POIdescription.getId());
ImageView imv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
imv.setImageBitmap(b);
imv.setId(presumed_id);
imv.setLayoutParams(params);
imv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
rl.addView(imv);
```

Problem is, when I dynamically add images (lets say three of them), they have huge spacing between them. I tried to set Padding to 0,0,0,0 but this doesn't help. Do you know, where can be problem in my case?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the space is between the image+description wrapped in a RelativeLayout, maybe the spacing occurs on the RelativeLayout and not on the ImageView.

Or is the description above many images? A layout description could be helpful.

Also, sometimes images are not of the size you are hoping so, try using ScaleType = fitXY to see if it is a layout problem or image size.

Regards